# Please explain Discriminator and DiscriminatorValue Concept in RAML 1.0

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mulesoft, mule-esb

I cannot understand the concept of Discriminator and Discriminator Value defined in RAML 1.0 described here in this [link]:https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-10/raml-10.md/#security-scheme-types

Can anyone please help with certain video or with any small project illustrating the same concept ?
Thanks in anticipation .

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just forget the RAML for a moment. It is a generic concept.

**Lets run through an example**

```
Vehicle vehicleOne = new Car("1", ...);
Vehicle vehicleTwo = new Van("2", ....);
Vehicle vehicleThree = new Bus("2", ....);
    
List<Vehicle> vehicleList = asList(vehicleOne, vehicleTwo, vehicleThree);
```

**Now assume**

- you cannot do `instanceof` or `getClass`
- you have been given this list of vehicles
- you have to tell what kind of vehicles are in the list

**Now if this is also true**

- the vehicle had a `field` called `vehicleType`
- Car was created with `car` as `vehicleType`
- Van was created with `van` as `vehicleType`
- Bus was created with  `bus` as `vehicleType`

**Solution**

You can easily achieve your goal by calling `vehicle.getVehicleType` and checking the value it contains

**What is discriminator in this use-case**

- it is a unique field name that hold different value for each vehicle.
- so in this case, `vehicleType` is called `discriminator`

**What is discriminator value in this usecase**

- For Car vehicle type, you stored `car` in the `vehicleType` field so `car` is one `discriminatorValue`
- For Van vehicle type, you stored `van` in the `vehicleType` field so `van` is another `discriminatorValue`
- For Bus vehicle type, you stored `bus` in the `vehicleType` field so `bus` is another `discriminatorValue`

**Summary:**

Field name which belong to all sub types types and have a unique value for each type is called discriminator. Then what you store in that field is discriminatorValue.

You might need discriminator/discriminatorValue in many places when you have sub types and need to differentiate.

- It may be storing car, bus and van in a single database table
- It may be calling REST endpoint where the single endpoint can accept car, van or bus as parameter. (That is your case)